# JHipster rest api permit only microservice

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, jhipster

I have a JHipster Microservice application in which there is a dependency between 2 microservices, msA and msB.

1. A user makes a rest call to msA
2. msA processes the request and makes an AuthorizedFeignClient call to a rest endpoint on msB to perform some other logic with the user.

My problem is, the logic performed in msB is only internal, needs to know the user and should not be exposed to the outside user. How can I restrict the rest endpoint on msB so that only another microservice can make requests to it and not a public user?

Comment: By authenticating and authorizing it, just as you would a human user to an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- require some specific role for this endpoint and assign this role to an internal user that msA will use. Both oauth2 and uaa auth types in JHipster define an `internal` client id and secret that you can customize for this use case.
- do not expose this endpoint as a route of your API gateway through Zuul routes configuration in gateway's `application.yml` as inter-service communication does not go through gateway

Comment: From [link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html) it seems I need to use _ignoredPatterns_ but it doesn't seem to work. I configured like so in my gateway application.yml. 
zuul:
    ignoredPatterns:
        - "service/api/endpoint"

Comment: It should work, did you make the change in the registry central config files or locally? Try to run under debugger to see if your settings are read?